# Unable Install MVC 4.0 Runtime in my local Machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed in my local machine and to support one of the old framework project, I do need to install MVC 4.0 Runtime in my local macine.

Tried installing VS 2010 SP1 but not seeing "Microsoft.ASP.NET MVC 4.0 Runtime" under installed programs.

Can anyone suggest how can I get this installed in my local machine?

Comment: Hi, open *Visual Studio Installer*, then open *Components* tab and find ***ASP.NET MVC 4*** and install it. If the first way doesn't help you - read [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc4) and try install earlier version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the steps what I have executed did installed the MVC 4 Runtime. But it is not showing as a program under my control panel. All Good.